# What was in the present from Robert to Sandy in A Patch Of Fog

Tags: plot-explanation, a-patch-of-fog

In the last scene of [A Patch Of Fog](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2181282/) we can see a present from Robert to Sandy Duffy.
Is there any indication or hint given to what is in that present?
I believe it could be the manuscript or the security cam footage but these are just wild guesses.

The tag on the present has the following text:

> TO SANDY
>
> FROM ROBERT
>
> MERRY XMAS
>
> DEATH TO ELEPHANTS

Here is a screenshot from the scene:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Its the manuscript, Robert wanted to give it back to Sandy as a sign of true friendship (whatever that meant in Robert's twisted mind).

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.